# IF con Extending SQL en PostgreSQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Intento hacer esto en **postgres**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.busqueda_productos(_parametro character 
varying,_descripcion character varying,_estado character varying)
 RETURNS SETOF productos AS
 $BODY$
IF ($1 ='General' )then 
  SELECT * FROM productos WHERE descripcion ilike _descripcion||'%';
ELSIF ($1 ='Activo' )then 
SELECT * FROM productos WHERE descripcion ilike _descripcion||'%' and 
estado=_estado;
 END IF;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
```

---

Y me sale este error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IF"
>   LINE 4: IF ($1 ='General' )then 
>           ^

**Error**

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
>   SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 180

Answer (score 2):

No puedes usar `IF ... ELSEIF ... END IF;` en una función definida como de lenguaje `SQL`, porque este tipo de condiciones forma parte del lenguaje `PL/pgSQL`, no `SQL`.

De modo que tienes por lo menos 2 opciones. Escoge la que te parezca más apropiada.

#### 1. Expresar las condiciones en SQL puro

Si quieres definir la función usando solamente SQL, entonces en vez de usar condiciones con `IF ... ELSIF ... END IF;`, esto lo puedes expresar en una consulta SQL usando condiciones `AND` y `OR`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.busqueda_productos(
    _parametro character varying,
    _descripcion character varying,
    _estado character varying)
 RETURNS SETOF productos AS
 $BODY$
   select *
     from productos
    where (_parametro = 'General' and descripcion ilike _descripcion||'%')
      or  (_parametro = 'Activo' and descripcion ilike _descripcion||'%' and estado=_estado);
 $BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

#### 2. Definir la función usando el lenguaje PL/pgSQL

Si tu deseo realmente es usar condiciones para usar una consulta u otra dependiendo del valor de `_parametro`, entonces debes usar `PL/pgSQL`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.busqueda_productos(
    _parametro character varying,
    _descripcion character varying,
    _estado character varying)
 RETURNS SETOF productos AS
 $BODY$
 begin
   if _parametro = 'General' then
      RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM productos WHERE descripcion ilike _descripcion||'%';
   elsif _parametro = 'Activo' then
      RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM productos WHERE descripcion ilike _descripcion||'%' and estado=_estado;
   end if;
 end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```